# Not able to process json string data in golang struct

Tags: json, go

I have a json data in string (coming from third party API). I am not able to decode json string data in golang.

Please help.

JSON string =

```
{
        "data" : {
                 "additional-30":  {
                       "id_sales_rule_set": 255626,
                        "voucher_code": "PR35ZR5J5",
                         "from_date": "2015-06-16 16:19:22",
                         "to_date": "2018-09-28 23:59:59",
                         "conditions_ruleset": {
                             "subTotal": 0,
                              "category": {},
                              "customer": "0",
                              "paymentMethod": null,
                              "capOnDiscount": null,
                              "skuExclude": null,
                              "discountedItem": 0,
                              "discounted": 1500,
                              "taggedItem": null,
                              "segmentedVoucher": null,
                              "bundle": null,
                              "brand": null,
                              "mobileVoucher": null,
                              "itemAttribute": {}
                         },
                        "discount_type": "fixed",
                        "discount_percentage": null,
                        "discount_amount_default": 500
        },
        "abcd":  {
                       "id_sales_rule_set": 255626,
                        "voucher_code": "PR35ZR5J5",
                         "from_date": "2015-06-16 16:19:22",
                         "to_date": "2018-09-28 23:59:59",
                         "conditions_ruleset": {
                             "subTotal": 0,
                              "category": {},
                              "customer": "0",
                              "paymentMethod": null,
                              "capOnDiscount": null,
                              "skuExclude": null,
                              "discountedItem": 0,
                              "discounted": 1500,
                              "taggedItem": null,
                              "segmentedVoucher": null,
                              "bundle": null,
                              "brand": null,
                              "mobileVoucher": null,
                              "itemAttribute": {}
                         },
                        "discount_type": "fixed",
                        "discount_percentage": null,
                        "discount_amount_default": 500
        } 
    }
}
```

Struct in which I want to get data

```
type ConditionsRuleset struct {
        Brand            interface{} `json:"brand"`
        Bundle           interface{} `json:"bundle"`
        CapOnDiscount    interface{} `json:"capOnDiscount"`
        Category         struct{}    `json:"category"`
        Customer         string      `json:"customer"`
        Discounted       int         `json:"discounted"`
        DiscountedItem   int         `json:"discountedItem"`
        ItemAttribute    struct{}    `json:"itemAttribute"`
        MobileVoucher    interface{} `json:"mobileVoucher"`
        PaymentMethod    interface{} `json:"paymentMethod"`
        SegmentedVoucher interface{} `json:"segmentedVoucher"`
        SkuExclude       interface{} `json:"skuExclude"`
        SubTotal         int         `json:"subTotal"`
        TaggedItem       interface{} `json:"taggedItem"`
    }

type PromoVoucher struct {
    ConditionsRuleset ConditionsRuleset `json:"conditions_ruleset"`
    DiscountAmountDefault int         `json:"discount_amount_default"`
    DiscountPercentage    interface{} `json:"discount_percentage"`
    DiscountType          string      `json:"discount_type"`
    FromDate              string      `json:"from_date"`
    IDSalesRuleSet        int         `json:"id_sales_rule_set"`
    ToDate                string      `json:"to_date"`
    VoucherCode           string      `json:"voucher_code"`
}

type PromoCacheData struct {
    Data map[string]interface{} `json:"data"`
}
```

Here is my code where I want to process json

```
by := []byte(<json string>)
    tmp := new(PromoCacheData)
    json.Unmarshal(by,tmp)

    for k,value := range *tmp {

        byc, _ := json.Marshal(value)
        tmp2 := new(PromoVoucher)
        json.Unmarshal(byc,tmp2)
        fmt.Println(tmp2)
    }
```

Error I am getting : `cannot range over *tmp (type PromoCacheData)`

Comment: First of all, it should most probably be `for k,v := range tmp.Data` as you're iterating over the `Data` field (you can't range over a structure). Second of all, why not creating `map[string]PromoVoucher` instead of this magic in the for loop?

Comment: Also make sure you check the error values returned by json.Unmarshal and json.Marshal

Comment: sorry guys!! I am new in go so didn't understand the error message. @tomasz big help to know that we can't iterate over stuct. thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `tmp.Data` in for loop instead of `*tmp`.
Error message says that exactly